# Laravel request->input('') or old('') always return 1 in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to get the url data into my input value.

> Example:
>
> - the url is http://example.com/user?username=example
> - and my html input code is as below
> - `<input value="{{ request()->input('username') or old('username') }}">`
> - but the result always return "1" and not "example"

It seems like the "or" blade helper acts as conditional operator.

How can I get the username value from url into that input and still get the default value as old('username')?

Comment: how is my question doesn't follow how to ask? what I have tried is on the title?

Comment: `or` is indeed a conditional operator. It works well in situations like `@if(request()->input('username') or old('username'))` but not `{{ request()->input('username') or old('username') }}`

Comment: the statement is (A or B) so it evaluates to either true(1) or false(0) ... it cannot evaluate to 'example'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
<input value="{{ request()->input('username', old('username')) }}">
```

It will retrieve username as an input if it exists or default to the old value. You can also give a default value to the old helper.

Comment: This work but when I modified the value of the input and hit register button, the value I just entered doesn't stick around. Instead the value in the url always appear when I click register button.

Comment: @DaraDev Add method="POST" to your form element. The default GET method will indeed add parameters to your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler this way:

```
<input value="{{ (old('username')?old('username'):'') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple way.

```
<input value="{{ request()->input('username') ?? old('username') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation **8.x**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request)

We use the helper `request`

> The request function returns the current request instance or obtains
> an input field's value from the current request:

```
$request = request();

$value = request('key', $default);
```

> the value of request is an array you can simply retrieve your input using the input key as follow

```
$username = request()->username; //for http://example.com/user?username=example
```